# How to estimate how many storage will fabric peer occupy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How to estimate how many storage will fabric peer occupy?
If I have a main struct (the biggest size and used in high frequency ) in chaincode.
I found the storage of a peer's ledger is almost equal to the size of the data of main struct multiplied by 5~10.
Also the world state storage is almost the same with the ledger.

Comment: It is very difficult to estimate. The transaction size depends mainly on its readset, writeset, input and output parameters, events and number of endorsements. Then you have the block; e.g., if the batch timeout triggers with an only transaction, that block will have an only transaction (so it will have more header overhead per transaction). Concerning the world state, apart from the documents themselves, its size increases as you define indexes. You can save some storage by disabling the ledger history DB... Difficult to estimate. Better you check it empirically....

Comment: Yes，i found it is very complicated after viewed the envolope struct of the tx and the block struct, it is better to inspect the data of tx and block in storage. Thank you!